# Chosen.js on a dynamically created dropdown

Tags: jquery

This is NOT a duplicated question. I have looked at the other ones and they asked for something different.

When I create a static `OPTIONS` list. It works perfectly and I can choose items and remove items from my *Chosen Multi Select Box*.

So I then remove the static code and replace it with a `ajax` call to fill the list dynamically. The items look identical to the Static ones, but the list just does not work.

I have a list which is created with a ajax call.

Here is the code for that dynamic list.

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     url: "./api/genericHandler.php?argument=optionsKeywords",
>     type: 'POST',
>     success: function(data) {
>         var json = $.parseJSON(data);
>         $.each(json, function() {
>             var obj = json.shift();
>             $( "#media_keywords" ).append( "<option value="+obj.uuid+">"+ obj.key_word + "</option>" );
>         });
>     }
> });
> ```

I even tried to create the `<li>` items myself (which are created by the plugin). It shows the items but never 'makes' the selection.

> ```
>     $('.chosen-container').click(function(){
>         $.ajax({
>             url: "./api/genericHandler.php?argument=optionsKeywords",
>             type: 'POST',
>             success: function(json) {
>                 var myIndex = 0;
>                 var data = $.parseJSON(json);
>                 $.each(data, function() {
>                     var obj = data.shift();
>                     myIndex +=1;
>                     $( ".chosen-results" ).append( "<li class='active-result' data->option-array-index="+myIndex+" value=" +
>                      obj.uuid + ">" + obj.key_word + "</li>");
>                 });
>             }
>         });
>     });
> ```

Can someone help please?

**UPDATE**

If I manualy create the `<ul>` list as it should, I get the dropdown with the options, but if I choose a item. I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined` error on console.

This is where the `chosen` plugin tries toe set `item.selected = true;`
in the `Chosen.prototype.result_select = function(evt) {` function.

Sorry I know this is a bit random, but I realy dont know?

Comment: Could you try add this after populating dropdown:
`$("#media_keywords").chosen();`?

Comment: Yes I agree with what @Greenonion says, that ought to re-initialise the combo.

Comment: @Greenonion - Tried it like in the above edit now. Still not working. `OPTIONS` list is created in code, but the plugin doen not generate the `<ul>` list.

Comment: is there any chance your js code is executed before ajax returns any reslts?

Comment: Just looked at the docs here http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ looks like you need to use something like this, `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");` Groete van Plettenberg Baai!

Comment: It's wrong place to put `$("#media_keywords").chosen();` because you use asynk ajax call and chosen() will be called always before you updating your dropdown.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker - Yes Rob, that seemed to do it for me. Thanks. Enjoy the weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rob Schmuecker

Here is what did the job wor me.

> ```
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>     $.ajax({
>         url: "./api/genericHandler.php?argument=optionsKeywords",
>         type: 'POST',
>         success: function(data) {
>             var json = $.parseJSON(data);
>             $.each(json, function() {
>                 var obj = json.shift();
>                 $( "#media_keywords" ).append( "<option value="+obj.uuid+">"+ obj.key_word + "</option>" );
>             });
>
>         }
>     });
>
>     $('.chosen-container').click(function(){          //--------\
>         $("#media_keywords").trigger("chosen:updated");          |--- THIS BIT
>     });                                               //--------/
> });
> ```